# Adjust preview image preview size in camera API 2 android

Tags: java, android

I am creating a custom camera app. The height of my TextureView is set to 300 dp.

I want to set the video resolution as 640 x 480 with a preview height of 300dp(TextureView Height).

I want the camera preview to fill this area without stretching or cropping. How do I achieve this?

```java
public class VideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

        private static final int SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES = 90;
        private static final int SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES = 270;
        private static final SparseIntArray DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
        private static final SparseIntArray INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

        private static final String TAG = "Camera2VideoFragment";
        private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS = 1;
        private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

        private static final String[] VIDEO_PERMISSIONS = {
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        };

        static {
            DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
            DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
            DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
            DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
        }

        static {
            INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 270);
            INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 180);
            INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 90);
            INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 0);
        }

        private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;

        private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;

        /**
         * A reference to the current {@link android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession} for
         * preview.
         */
        private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession;

        /**
         * {@link TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener} handles several lifecycle events on a
         * {@link TextureView}.
         */
        private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
                = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                                  int width, int height) {
                openCamera(width, height);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                                    int width, int height) {
                configureTransform(width, height);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            }

        };

        /**
         * The {@link android.util.Size} of camera preview.
         */
        private Size mPreviewSize;

        /**
         * The {@link android.util.Size} of video recording.
         */
        private Size mVideoSize;

        /**
         * MediaRecorder
         */
        private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

        /**
         * Whether the app is recording video now
         */
        private boolean mIsRecordingVideo;

        /**
         * An additional thread for running tasks that shouldn't block the UI.
         */
        private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

        /**
         * A {@link Handler} for running tasks in the background.
         */
        private Handler mBackgroundHandler;

        /**
         * A {@link Semaphore} to prevent the app from exiting before closing the camera.
         */
        private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);

        /**
         * {@link CameraDevice.StateCallback} is called when {@link CameraDevice} changes its status.
         */
        private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
                mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
                startPreview();
                mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
                if (null != mTextureView) {
                    configureTransform(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
                mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
                cameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
                mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
                cameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
                Activity activity = VideoActivity.this;
                if (null != activity) {
                    activity.finish();
                }
            }

        };
        private Integer mSensorOrientation;
        private String mNextVideoAbsolutePath;
        private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;

        /**
         * In this sample, we choose a video size with 3x4 aspect ratio. Also, we don't use sizes
         * larger than 1080p, since MediaRecorder cannot handle such a high-resolution video.
         *
         * @param choices The list of available sizes
         * @return The video size
         */
        private static Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
            for (Size size : choices) {
                if (size.getWidth() == size.getHeight() * 4 / 3 && size.getWidth() <= 1080) {
                    return size;
                }
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable video size");
            return choices[choices.length - 1];
        }

        /**
         * Given {@code choices} of {@code Size}s supported by a camera, chooses the smallest one whose
         * width and height are at least as large as the respective requested values, and whose aspect
         * ratio matches with the specified value.
         *
         * @param choices     The list of sizes that the camera supports for the intended output class
         * @param width       The minimum desired width
         * @param height      The minimum desired height
         * @param aspectRatio The aspect ratio
         * @return The optimal {@code Size}, or an arbitrary one if none were big enough
         */
        private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
            // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
            List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
            int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
            int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
            for (Size option : choices) {
                if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w &&
                        option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
                    bigEnough.add(option);
                }
            }

            // Pick the smallest of those, assuming we found any
            if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
                return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
                return choices[0];
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

            mTextureView = findViewById(R.id.texture);

        }



        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            startBackgroundThread();
            if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
                openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            } else {
                mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            closeCamera();
            stopBackgroundThread();
            super.onPause();
        }

        /**
         * Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}.
         */
        private void startBackgroundThread() {
            mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
            mBackgroundThread.start();
            mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
        }

        /**
         * Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}.
         */
        private void stopBackgroundThread() {
            mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
            try {
                mBackgroundThread.join();
                mBackgroundThread = null;
                mBackgroundHandler = null;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Gets whether you should show UI with rationale for requesting permissions.
         *
         * @param permissions The permissions your app wants to request.
         * @return Whether you can show permission rationale UI.
         */
    //    private boolean shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(String[] permissions) {
    //        for (String permission : permissions) {
    //            if (FragmentCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {
    //                return true;
    //            }
    //        }
    //        return false;
    //    }


        /**
         * Tries to open a {@link CameraDevice}. The result is listened by `mStateCallback`.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
        private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
    //        if (!hasPermissionsGranted(VIDEO_PERMISSIONS)) {
    //            requestVideoPermissions();
    //            return;
    //        }
            final Activity activity = this;
            if (null == activity || activity.isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }
            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "tryAcquire");
                if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
                }
                String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[1];

                // Choose the sizes for camera preview and video recording
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
                if (map == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot get available preview/video sizes");
                }
                mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                        width, height, mVideoSize);

                int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                } else {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
                }
                configureTransform(width, height);
                mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Cannot access the camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                activity.finish();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
                // device this code runs.
    //            Camera2VideoFragment.ErrorDialog.newInstance("cammera error")
    //                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.");
            }
        }

        private void closeCamera() {
            try {
                mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
                closePreviewSession();
                if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                    mCameraDevice.close();
                    mCameraDevice = null;
                }
                if (null != mMediaRecorder) {
                    mMediaRecorder.release();
                    mMediaRecorder = null;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.");
            } finally {
                mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Start the camera preview.
         */
        private void startPreview() {
            if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                closePreviewSession();
                SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
                assert texture != null;
                texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

                Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
                mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

                mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(previewSurface),
                        new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                                mPreviewSession = session;
                                updatePreview();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                                Activity activity = VideoActivity.this;
                                if (null != activity) {
                                    Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }, mBackgroundHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Update the camera preview. {@link #startPreview()} needs to be called in advance.
         */
        private void updatePreview() {
            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(mPreviewBuilder);
                HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
                thread.start();
                mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(CaptureRequest.Builder builder) {
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        }

        /**
         * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
         * This method should not to be called until the camera preview size is determined in
         * openCamera, or until the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
         *
         * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
         * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
         */
        private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
            Activity activity = VideoActivity.this;
            if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
                return;
            }
            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
            RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
            float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
            if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
                bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
                matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
                float scale = Math.max(
                        (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                        (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
                matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
            }
            mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
        }

        private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
            final Activity activity = VideoActivity.this;
            if (null == activity) {
                return;
            }
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()) {
                mNextVideoAbsolutePath = getVideoFilePath(VideoActivity.this);
            }
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mNextVideoAbsolutePath);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            switch (mSensorOrientation) {
                case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES:
                    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
                    break;
                case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES:
                    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
                    break;
            }
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        }

        private String getVideoFilePath(Context context) {
            final File dir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
            return (dir == null ? "" : (dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/"))
                    + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";
        }

        private void startRecordingVideo() {
            if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                closePreviewSession();
                setUpMediaRecorder();
                SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
                assert texture != null;
                texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
                List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();

                // Set up Surface for the camera preview
                Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
                surfaces.add(previewSurface);
                mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

                // Set up Surface for the MediaRecorder
                Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
                surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
                mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

                // Start a capture session
                // Once the session starts, we can update the UI and start recording
                mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        updatePreview();
                        VideoActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // UI
                                mIsRecordingVideo = true;

                                // Start recording
                                mMediaRecorder.start();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        Activity activity = VideoActivity.this;
                        if (null != activity) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, mBackgroundHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private void closePreviewSession() {
            if (mPreviewSession != null) {
                mPreviewSession.close();
                mPreviewSession = null;
            }
        }

        private void stopRecordingVideo() {
            // UI
            mIsRecordingVideo = false;
    //        mButtonVideo.setText("record");
            // Stop recording
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();

            Activity activity = VideoActivity.this;
            if (null != activity) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Video saved: " + mNextVideoAbsolutePath,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "Video saved: " + mNextVideoAbsolutePath);
            }
            mNextVideoAbsolutePath = null;
            startPreview();
        }

        /**
         * Compares two {@code Size}s based on their areas.
         */
        static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

            @Override
            public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
                // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
                return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                        (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
            }

        }

    //    public static class ErrorDialog extends DialogFragment {
    //
    //        private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";
    //
    //        public static Camera2VideoFragment.ErrorDialog newInstance(String message) {
    //            Camera2VideoFragment.ErrorDialog dialog = new Camera2VideoFragment.ErrorDialog();
    //            Bundle args = new Bundle();
    //            args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
    //            dialog.setArguments(args);
    //            return dialog;
    //        }
    //
    //        @Override
    //        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //            final Activity activity = getActivity();
    //            return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    //                    .setMessage(getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE))
    //                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    //                        @Override
    //                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
    //                            activity.finish();
    //                        }
    //                    })
    //                    .create();
    //        }
    //
    //    }

        public void Record(View view)
        {
            if (mIsRecordingVideo) {
                stopRecordingVideo();
            } else {
                startRecordingVideo();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have same problem, Do you have any solution?